# Dense and continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Can a function $f:[0.1] \mapsto [0,1]$, is the set $S$ $$S=\{(a,b)\;|\; f(a)=b\}$$ dense in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ if the function is continuous?

Comment: What does it mean for a graph to be continuous?

Comment: @GuidoA. he prob means function, in which case the answer is obviously no thanks to the vertical line test and continuity.

Comment: Yes, in that case it is false, so that's why I was asking, just in case. What's the line test, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous it's graph is closed and so if it is dense, it has to be $[0,1]^2$. This contradicts $f$ being a *function*: given $x$ in $[0,1]$ there is only one element in its graph with first coordinate $x$.

Comment: Makes sense, that's what I thought, just couldn't think of why. Thanks.